# Determine when a loud sound is played in C#

Tags: c#, audio

I want to determine if another program plays a sound above a certain threshold. I am not looking for checking the volume settings on the computer or anything like that. I really just need to see if any app plays something higher then what I am expecting. Anyone know if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: My immediate response is that there's no "out-of-the-box" way of doing that with .Net. Probably need lower-level access to sound hardware. Even then, I don't think you can get the actual physical volume played because this can be controlled externally from the computer (using the volumne knob). :)

Comment: I'd think a program that does that would have to dig pretty deep into the system infrastructure, like, close to the sound card driver. Maybe DirectX allows you to go there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/volumemeter.aspx) project on codeproject.  It's a volume meter using managed DirectX and written entirely in C#.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sources of possible sound on the local machine and ultimately these will communicate via the Windows Sound System down to a mixer and out through the sound card. The only way that I know of to monitor all sounds on a Windows system is to write a Filter Driver using the Device Driver Development Kit. This would intercept all requests to the sound system , walk through the data that is being sent for play and could set flags/write to a log when it spots large differences (where abs(data[x+1] - data[x]) is a large value).

Driver development is usually done in C. There is a bunch of sample code out there on the web if you want to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

[This looks like a good place to start your investigation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370802%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  I don't think that you'll find what you're looking for built into .Net already, though.